# Angular form reset() does not return to pristine status

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I have a form made with Angular 8 and I want that everytime I validate it, it also reset the field back to normal (pristine).
But the behaviour I get instead is that form fields get emptied, but tagged as invalid as well.

According to angular documentation, reset() should not behave like that

Any idea?

**Controller:**

```
add() {
        if (this.form.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        const account = new Account();

        account.role = this.form.get('role').value;
        account.lastname = this.form.get('lastname').value;
        account.firstname = this.form.get('firstname').value;
        account.function = this.form.get('function').value;
        account.email = this.form.get('email').value;
        account.phone = this.form.get('phone').value;

        this.offer.account.push(account);

        this.update();
        this.form.reset();
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="add()">
    <div class="w-100 my-4">
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
            <mat-toolbar-row>
                <span>Account</span>
            </mat-toolbar-row>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </div>

    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">

        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-2">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="w-100">
                <mat-select placeholder="Role" id="account-role" formControlName="role">
                    <mat-option [value]="'ADMIN'">Admin</mat-option>
                    <mat-option [value]="'MANAGER'">Manager</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="w-100">
                <input matInput placeholder="Lastname"
                       id="account-lastname"
                       formControlName="lastname">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="w-100">
                <input matInput placeholder="Firstname"
                       id="account-firstname"
                       formControlName="firstname">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="w-100">
                <input matInput placeholder="Function"
                       id="account-function"
                       formControlName="function">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-2">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="w-100">
                <input matInput placeholder="E-mail"
                       id="account-email"
                       formControlName="email">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="w-100">
                <input matInput placeholder="Phone"
                       id="account-phone"
                       formControlName="phone">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="float-right mt-3" [disabled]="isDisabled()">
                Add
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceAccount" class="mat-elevation-z8 w-100 mt-4 mb-5">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Role</th>
        <td mat-cell
            *matCellDef="let account">{{ account.getRoleName() }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Lastname</th>
        <td mat-cell
            *matCellDef="let account">{{ account.lastname }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Firstname</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let account">{{ account.firstname }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="function">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Function</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let account">{{ account.function }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>E-mail</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let account">{{ account.email }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Phone</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let account">{{ account.phone }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="accountDisplayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: accountDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Look like already open issue is there is material: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4190

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Controller:**

```
form = new FormGroup({
    lastname: new FormControl(),
    firstname: new FormControl(),
    function: new FormControl(),
    email: new FormControl(),
    phone: new FormControl(),
  });

.....

add() {
        if (this.form.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        const account = new Account();

        account.role = this.form.controls.role;
        account.lastname = this.form.controls.lastname;
        account.firstname = this.form.controls.firstname;
        account.function = this.form.controls.function;
        account.email = this.form.controls.email;
        account.phone = this.form.controls.phone;

        this.offer.account.push(account);

        this.update();
        this.form.reset();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'string'.` And indeed, all these Account properties are typed as string (which makes sense)

Comment: Should work for inputs, looks like this error related to mat-select. console.log(this.form) in ngOnInit() life cycle, but remove mat-select for test purpose.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-autocomplete-formcontrol